# How to include quotes in a string vba

Tags: string, vba, excel

I want to store the following text

```
"Test1":"Monday","Test_Abcdef":":"
```

All including quotes in a string

I understand that to include a quote in a string I have to include `""` before a `"` but here it's not a very good solution as I have too many of them in a text.

Any Idea how I can do it all at once?

Comment: Could you use a replace function: `Replace(Selection, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two choices: you can either use two instances for each one, e.g.

```
"Test1"":""Monday"",""Test_Abcdef"":"":"
```

or you can use `Chr(34)`:

```
"Test1" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "Monday" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "Test_Abcdef" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & ":"
```

Comment: I used the second method it's easy to implement.