# Appending multiple lines to a string variable in VBA is causing a compile error: Expected: Expression

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing a Compile error, expected expression error on the first line of this code.

I've declared htmlbod as a string variable to add my html code

```
 htmlbod = & "<p>Attached you will find lorem ipsum</p>" _
 htmlbod = & "<p>Open the report lorem ipsum</p>" _
 htmlbod = & "<p>od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud e</p>" _
 htmlbod = & "od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud e" _
 htmlbod = & "od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud e" _
 htmlbod = & "<p>od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud e</p>" _
 htmlbod = & "<p>od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud e</p>" _
 htmlbod = & "<p>od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud e</p>" _
 htmlbod = & "<p>od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud e</p>" _
 htmlbod = & "<p>Lod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud e</p>" _
 htmlbod = & "<p>Thanks,</p>" _
```

I am then using
`.HTMLBody = htmlbod`
to define my email's body.

When I go to the next line after the last htmlbod append, the VBA editor highlights the first "&" in the first line (`& "<p>Attached you will find lorem ipsum</p>" _`) and displays compile error, expected expression error.
I've added a line continuation for every line as well.

I'm not sure what the error here is.
Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Edit: I made the necessary changes and it's working but certain lines still have an error (The lines with a style component in them)
`htmlbod = htmlbod & "<p>od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud e<span style="text-decoration: underline;"> minim veniam </span> quis nostrud <strong>&gt;100,000,000.</strong></p>"`

Comment: Remove the first `&` from the first line and remove all the `htmlbod ` from all other lines. Alternatively, remove all the"`_`" at the end of each line add `htmlbod ` before the `&` of each line except the first one where you should remove the `&`. in both cases remove the very last `_`

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30999) may prove useful

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it worked!
It worked for most lines but some lines have a style component in it, which I think is confusing the compiler
' htmlbod = htmlbod & "<p>od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud e<span style="text-decoration: underline;"> minim veniam </span> quis nostrud <strong>&gt;100,000,000.</strong></p>" '
How can I tackle this?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132737/how-to-include-quotes-in-a-string-vba

Comment: HTML is fine with single quotes, so you can use (eg) `HTML = "<span style='font:bold'>Content</span>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to create a long String:

Either you do this with a single statement that consists of several source lines. You can achieve this by putting an  `_` (space + underscore) at the end of a line, this will signal that the next line belongs to the statement:

```
htmlbody = "<p>Attached you will find lorem ipsum</p>" _
         & "<p>Open the report lorem ipsum</p>" _
         & "<p>od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim </p>"
```

This is just a readable form of

```
htmlbody = "<p>Attached you will find lorem ipsum</p>" & "<p>Open the report lorem ipsum</p>" & "<p>od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim </p>"
```

Note that you can have a maximum of 24 of those concatenated code lines, else the VBA editor will complain.

The second way is to create the string with several single statements:

```
htmlbody = "<p>Attached you will find lorem ipsum</p>"
htmlbody = htmlbody & "<p>Open the report lorem ipsum</p>" 
htmlbody = htmlbody & "<p>od tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim </p>"
```

This is a little bit less performant (but you will not be able to measure it, so don't worry). So which method you choose is a matter of taste.

Your code, however, did an invalid mixture of both methods. The compiler sees something like

```
htmlbod = & "<p>Attached you will find lorem ipsum</p>" htmlbod = & "<p>Open the report lorem ipsum</p>"
```

and it's easy to see that this is not a valid syntax.

Comment: This works as advertised, could you also look at my comment above regarding a follow-up.